# Mixing <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service with @Autowired dependency coming back as null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc 3.0 web application and am using a conversion-service as follows...

```
<bean id="applicationConversionService"
    class="com.myer.reporting.converter.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myer.reporting.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myer.reporting.manager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myer.reporting.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myer.reporting.dao.mapper"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>
```

In my controllers when i use the conversion service it all works fine.

```
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean applicationConversionService;   '
```

But for the first time I am now trying to use the applicationConversionService in my mapper using the same method but the applicationConversionService is always coming back as null.

```
package com.myer.reporting.dao.mapper;

public class ImportHistoryRowMapper implements RowMapper<ImportHistory> {

    private static final String BUSINESS_DATE = "businessdate";
    private static final String TOTAL_TRAN_COUNT = "total_tran_count";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean applicationConversionService;

    public ImportHistory mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Date businessDate = rs.getDate(BUSINESS_DATE);
        Integer totalTranCount = rs.getInt(TOTAL_TRAN_COUNT);

        ImportHistory importHistory = new ImportHistory();
        importHistory.setBusinessDate(businessDate);
        importHistory.setTransactionCount(totalTranCount);

        // status
        TrafficLightStatus status = 
                applicationConversionService.
                getImportThresholdToStatusConverter()
                .convert(totalTranCount);   
        importHistory.setStatus(status);
        return importHistory;
    }
}
```

I tried to add @Component to the top of the class but that doesn't seem to work either. I think I am lacking some understanding of the @Autowired annotation and therefore can't get this to work.

Can someone give me some advice on this please.

thanks

Comment: How are you calling ImportHistoryRowMapper, is it by new opertor or spring managed?

Comment: List<ImportHistory> importHistory =    
   getJdbcTemplate().query (
     IMPORT_HISTORY_LOOKUP_SQL,
     new Object[]{sqlDateString},
     new ImportHistoryRowMapper());

Comment: Yes you are right. It is not spring managed. That is the issue. But then what is the right way to fix this.

Comment: Create a bean for it and just inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the ImportHistoryRowMapper spring managed for this to work.
I believe your dao class making the reference to this mapper class is singleton. For every request (i.e., call to method getJdbcTemplate().query ( sql, object array, new instance of ImportHistoryRowMapper);), you need to create new instance of ImportHistoryRowMapper i.e., it should be prototype.
You can inject prototype bean into singleton in 2 ways:

1) [Lookup Method injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection)
2) [Scoped proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-scoped-proxy)

Take a look at [this](http://prasanthnath.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/injecting-a-prototype-bean-into-a-singleton-bean/comment-page-1/).